# lowest tier price on home page is not showing

Tags: magento-1.7, price

I have following codes on my home page product listing. I have to calculate the difference between lowest tier price and normal price of a product, But I can't find the lowest tier price. All other information about product are coming but lowest tier price. I can't understant what to do as I am new to magento. Please help. 
Here is the code snippet..

```
<?php  
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();  
$_productCollection=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_featured', 1)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
        ->joinField('value','catalog_product_entity_tier_price','value', 'entity_id=entity_id','{{table}}.website_id='.$storeId, 'left')
        ->setPageSize(9)
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId);  
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):  
$lowestTierPrice = product->getResource()->getAttribute('tier_price')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); //It is not working  
$normalPrice = $_product->getPrice();  //it works fine
```

print_r($_product->getTierPrice());  //getting all the tier price
    endforeach;

Comment: join ` ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()` to collecton got  getting mininal porice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting tier price you does not need to use

```
 ->joinField('value','catalog_product_entity_tier_price','value', 'entity_id=entity_id','{{table}}.website_id='.$storeId, 'left')
```

and

```
lowestTierPrice = product->getResource()->getAttribute('tier_price')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); //It is not working
```

**And add below code inside foreach loop.**

```
$TierPirce=Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_price')->getTierPrice(null,$_product);
```

Comment: $TierPirce=Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_price')->getTierPrice(null,$$_product);print_r($TierPirce); gives me only normal price.

Comment: there have syntax mistake.. i have edit that .. now see

Comment: I had modified that one "$$_product". It gives me normal price (one item).  but ->addMinimalPrice() ->addFinalPrice() ->addTaxPercents();  lowestTierPrice = product->getResource()->getAttribute('tier_price')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); gives me lowest tire price. is it right ?